# How to get mobile number in session of laravel

Tags: laravel-5.8

My project is, after a user come registered redirect to verification page.

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    Session::put('mobile',$mobile) 
    $code = rand(10000,99999);
    $user = User::create([
        'first_name' => $request->first_name,
        'last_name' => $request->last_name,
        'gender' => $request->gender,
        'mobile' => $request->mobile,
        //continue code
    }
    return redirect()->route('verification/?session'.$session);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of Session use

Session::get('mobile')

anywhere in the controller or in blade file or anywhere where Session::class accessible.